# Adding a permissions structure to a state-machine workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

is there any way to add permissions to a state-machine workflow for approvals so that if you try and set a state on an item that you are not supposed to, the change gets reversed?

More specifically, can this be done in SPD2010 without using a Visio workflow or a custom InfoPath form?

Comment: I know I made an encyclopedia-like post on creating a state machine workflow in SPD2010, but the one thing it lacks is a good permissions structure, and I'm not sure how to add that, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just need to add some sort of check within the state steps that if some field equals a specific value to go to a different state instead?  The other field could be something in the content type that is hidden so it's only accessible by the workflow.

Sort of a vague answer, but all I can think of at the moment.

Comment: Can it be done so that if a group of people have the access, that they can be checked by the user group/membership?

Comment: You could try doing a check If created by (or modified by) is part of a group, do something, but this has never really worked well in my experience.  I suppose you could create a separate tracking list of approved people (person/group column) and look up against that.

Comment: if this were done via a Visio workflow, or a custom-coded workflow, could the permissions restrictions be included into the workflow easier?

Comment: Most likely yes as you'd be able to enumerate the users permissions and groups easier.